# blenderで作ったアニメーションをunityで読み込んだ際に複製ができない

Tags: unity3d, blender

blenderで作ったアニメーションをunity上で編集するためにアニメーションを複製しようとすると、[Illegal characters in path]というconsoleが出てきてアニメーションをループさせたりBake Into Poseしたりすることができずに困ってます。どなたか解決方法をお願いします。